# How to use function CLSIDFromProgID within MINGW?

Tags: gcc

I want to get a ActiveX object's clsid.
I found function ClSIDFromProgID in objbase.h and included it;

```
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("Mycom.soft"),&clsid);
```

But when I compile it the compiler says:

```
 undefined reference to `CLSIDFromProgID@8'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at what the corresponding MSDN docs for the function in question ([`CLSIDFromProgID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in this case) state in regards to the import library. It's usually a safe bet that mingw uses the same library. Alternatively `grep` over the `.def` files in the mingw source.

MSDN states it is `ole32.lib` in this case, so you have to link with `-lole32` in mingw.

`grep` concurs:
`mingw-w64-crt/lib32/ole32.def:CLSIDFromProgID@8` -> `ole32.lib`